How to extract the mean value of a band in each image in a image collection in Google Earth Engine
I am trying to extract the mean value of a band in all of the images of a image collection so I can then plot the values in a box plot to find outliers etc.
So far I have created a function that calculates the  the mean of each of each images and adds it as a new layer. This isn't the output I need as  I think  I need the values in a list in order to chart them. How can a solve this problem?
//Summer collection
var SummerCollection = LandsatCol
                        .filterDate('2017-06-01', '2020-9-30')
                        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(9, 11,'month'));
                        

var mean = SummerCollection.select(['LST'], ['LST_mean']).mean();

var collectionWithMean = SummerCollection.map(function (image) {
  return image.addBands(mean);
});

Link to my code


If you just want to plot in the GEE code editor you can directly use ui.Chart.image.series which works with imageCollections and does the mean calculation automatically (through the use of the reducer). You can also use reduceRegion if you want to extract the mean values, which you use by mapping over your collection. I would suggest however defining a geometry and using it to filterBounds with your collection if you want to avoid mapping over thousands of tiles that aren't relevant to your script.

Solved by creating a function to reduce over the image collection and then extracting from dictionary to a list.
Link to code
var tempMeans = function(image){
  var reduct = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e10
  });
  // Extract the properties from the dictionary and then form the list
  reduct = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(reduct));

  // Put the results into a Feature without geometry
  return ee.Feature(null, reduct);
};

// Map the function
var result = SummerCollection.map(tempMeans );

print(result);

